# Translating a big website in PHP

Tags: php, translation, translate

Currently, I'm developping a very big project, with lots of pages, and I'm thinking which could be the best, and fastest, way to translate all the pages with PHP. I was looking for Po Edit, but actually I don't like it. Is there any other way to translate pages?

Answer (score 2):

The way I do this on my websites is with separate php 'languages' files, and an associative array.

```
<?php
    //english file - lang.english.php
    $language = array(
        "hello" => "hello",
        "today" => "today",
    );
?>


<?php
    //welsh file = lang.welsh.php
    $language = array(
        "hello" => "helo",
        "today" => "heddiw",
    );
?>
```

Then simply `include()` lang.english.php or lang.welsh.php depending on which language the user selected and use `<?php $language["hello"]; ?>` in your html to reference to translations.

This method assumes that you know the translations for each languages, and it may take a long time to create these language files, but once you have completed one it becomes very easy to add more.

Comment: Translating texts is only the easy part, the intermediate level is mixing numbers and text dynamically, and the hard part is to properly reference numbers and gender in multiple languages dynamically. It is not always as easy as "3 file(s) found".